# Jquery filter how to keep pervious checked valued

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm working on a multiple checkbox php jquery script but having difficulty keeping the value of a previous checked checkbox.

I could currently filter the vehicles makes and it displays the correct makes but when I click on a vehicle model the makes value disappear and only shows the models. How do i save the vehicle makes value?

**jQuery Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.makes').on('change',function(){ //on checkboxes check

        //sending checkbox value into serialize form
        var hi=$('.makes:checked').serialize();
        if(hi){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                url: "carfilter.php",
                data:{make:hi},
                success: function(response){
                    document.getElementById('getdata').style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById("getdata").innerHTML = response;
                    $('#result').hide();
                }
            });
        } else {
            document.getElementById('getdata').style.display = "none";
            $('#result').show();
        }
    });

    $('.models').on('change',function(){ //on checkboxes check

        //sending checkbox value into serialize form
        var hi=$('.models:checked').serialize();
        if(hi){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                url: "carfilter.php",
                data:{model:hi},
                success: function(response){
                    document.getElementById('getdata').style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById("getdata").innerHTML = response;
                    $('#result').hide();
                }
            });
        } else {
            document.getElementById('getdata').style.display = "none";
            $('#result').show();
        }
    });
});
```

**Check boxes**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingfoure">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseMakes" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseMakes">Refine By Make</a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseMakes" class="panel-collapse collapse out" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingfoure">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="cs-select-model">
                <ul class="cs-checkbox-list mCustomScrollbar" data-mcs-theme="dark">
                <?php
                    // connect to database
                    include 'config/config.php';
                    include 'config/opendb.php';

                    $chkbx = 0;
                    $sql="SELECT make, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM vehicles GROUP BY make ASC";
                    $rs=$conn->query($sql);

                    $rs->data_seek(0);
                    while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
                        $chkbx++;
                        echo"<li>
                                 <div class='checkbox'>
                                     <input type='checkbox' name='makes[]' value='{$row['make']}' id='{$row['make']}' class='makes' />
                                     <label for='{$row['make']}'>{$row['make']}</label>
                                     <span>({$row['cnt']})</span>
                                  </div>
                              </li>";
                      }
                  ?>
                  </ul>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingfoure">
          <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseModels" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseModels">Refine By Model</a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseModels" class="panel-collapse collapse out" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingfoure">
          <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="cs-select-model">
                  <ul class="cs-checkbox-list mCustomScrollbar" data-mcs-theme="dark">
                  <?php
                      $chkbx = 0;
                      $sql="SELECT model, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM vehicles GROUP BY model ASC";
                      $rs=$conn->query($sql);

                      $rs->data_seek(0);
                      while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
                          $chkbx++;
                          echo"<li>
                                   <div class='checkbox'>
                                       <input type='checkbox' name='models[]' value='{$row['model']}' id='{$row['model']}' class='models' />
                                       <label for='{$row['model']}'>{$row['model']}</label>
                                       <span>({$row['cnt']})</span>
                                   </div>
                               </li>";
                       }
                   ?>
                   </ul>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

**carfilter.php**

```
<?php
    // connect to database
    include 'config/config.php';
    include 'config/opendb.php';

   $sql="SELECT * FROM vehicles";

   if(!empty($_POST['make']) || !empty($_POST['model'])) {
       $sql.=" WHERE ";

       if(!empty($_POST['make'])) {
           //unserialize to jquery serialize variable value
           $brandis=array();
           parse_str($_POST['make'],$makeis); //changing string into array

           //split 1st array elements
           foreach($makeis as $manufacturer){
               $manufacturer;
           }

           $manufacturers=implode("','",$manufacturer); //change into comma separated value to sub array
           $sql.="make IN ('$manufacturers')";

           if(!empty($_POST['model'])){
               $sql.=" AND ";
           }
       }
       if(!empty($_POST['model'])) {
           //unserialize to jquery serialize variable value
           $modelis=array();
           parse_str($_POST['model'],$modelis); //changing string into array

           //split 1st array elements
           foreach($modelis as $model){
               $model;
           }
           $model=implode("','",$model); //change into comma separated value to sub array
           $sql .="model IN ('$model')";
       }
   }

   $sql.=" ORDER BY make, year DESC";
   $rs=$conn->query($sql);

   $rs->data_seek(0);
   $listviewNum = 0;
   while($rows = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
       // // show results
   }
```

Comment: When someone selects a model on your secondary ajax call send back an array of values, the current model selected and the previous make value selected. Currently you're sending back only one value hence why they initial value is lost.

Comment: I'm not good at javascript. How would that bee done? I am eventually going to have 5-6 filters. Do you think sending values back in an array is the best method?

Comment: I was trying to find a way to send each checkbox filter value to carfilters in its own variable while keeping the older values that have been already selected. So if a user selects bmw they can then after select m3 and then select red for color and so on.

Comment: Well your response will have record of both items selected. Since you're only sending back a single value the other value is being lost.

Comment: point taken how would i modify my jquery to pass the values?

Comment: review the answer posted below.

Comment: your code is somewhat redundant though. should extract the ajax function and put it in a standalone function. Then you only have to modify the code in one location and it will handle everything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of the secondary value when the user makes another filter request like so:

```
$('.models').on('change',function(){ //on checkboxes check

        //sending checkbox value into serialize form
        var hi=$('.models:checked').serialize();
        var hi2=$('.makes:checked').serialize();
        if(hi){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                url: "carfilter.php",
                data:{model:hi,
                      make:hi2},
                success: function(response){
                    document.getElementById('getdata').style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById("getdata").innerHTML = response;
                    $('#result').hide();
                }
            });
        } else {
            document.getElementById('getdata').style.display = "none";
            $('#result').show();
        }
    });
```

It appears the PHP code is already accounting for everything else.

Comment: yes it did. thank you. is there a way to make the code less redundant?

Comment: for the jquery section most certainly.